# Using Visual Basic Macros for debugging application - skipping to next breakpoint

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, macros, breakpoints

I have a program running. To test this program, I need only one breakpoint. This breakpoint hits between 7 and 8 times consecutively, where I need to change a value each time it breaks.

To accomplish this I am trying to write a macros to make it easier and faster to (rather than hitting continue after changing each value), but have hit a wall. My goal is to enter all values at once and have the macros set the values in the code for each break. Is there a way to continue to the next stop within the macros code?

Any pointers would be helpful as I am not a VB expert.

Thanks

Comment: Have you got a code example? What is it that you're changing?

Comment: Are you using Visual Basic or VBA (e.g. with Excel spreadsheets)?

Comment: @CJBS I have tried writing some code but have not been successful. What my code ended up doing is prompt me for a value for each break (which I can accomplish without a macros). I am using visual basic.

Comment: Please provide a code sample, and perhaps a screen-shot if possible.

Answer (score 0):

An expression is evaluated as part of the evaluation of a breakpoint condition. (Right-click the breakpoint in Visual Studio, and choose 'Condition'). This expression could call a function that you write (as part of your macro code), and within that function you could change and values that you need to change, and then return a Boolean that determines whether the breakpoint is actually hit.

Of course you could just incorporate such a function call directly into your code, and have a conditional expression with a breakpoint within the If.

Comment: I cannot change the code. This would have to work for testing multiple programs with this same platform base. I set a conditional break in my code to run my macros. My macros currently prompts for a set if numbers, then it will parse that set if numbers. ideally it would then use that set of numbers and use the first number for the first break, second number for the next break, and so on until there are no more numbers from the user (there is only one breakpoint that hits over and over).